# Global error handling and the order of included rescue_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, error-handling, module

For my program to work as expected, the order of rescue_from is not intuitive. I'm wondering why this is or where I'm going wrong?

I was trying this error handling solution.

https://medium.com/rails-ember-beyond/error-handling-in-rails-the-modular-way-9afcddd2fe1b#.yvuf06281

My error handler was the same as in the [github repo](https://github.com/scaffeinate/modular-error-handling/blob/master/lib/error/error_handler.rb)

```
module Error
  module ErrorHandler
    def self.included(clazz)
      clazz.class_eval do
        rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
          respond(:record_not_found, 404, e.to_s)
        end
        rescue_from CustomError do |e|
          respond(e.error, e.status, e.message.to_s)
        end
        rescue_from StandardError do |e|
          respond(:standard_error, 500, e.to_s)
        end
      end
    end
```

This results in my errors always being caught in the `StandardError` block, skipping the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and `Custom` error blocks.

However, if I switch the order (`StandardError` higher in the execution) it properly catches the other types of errors.

```
    def self.included(clazz) #includes module as a class method
      clazz.class_eval do
        rescue_from StandardError do |e|
          respond(:standard_error, 500, e.to_s) 
        end

        rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
          respond(:record_not_found, 404, e.to_s)
        end

        rescue_from CustomError do |e|
          respond(e.error, e.status, e.message.to_s)
        end
      end
    end
```

Why does having StandardError at the top work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [last declared handler has the highest priority](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/activesupport/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb#L124-L126), so you should declare general handlers first (e.g. one for `StandardError`) and then specific ones.